# mongoose atlas connection fails while mongodb driver works

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, replicaset

I need to connect to an Atlas replica set with mongoose. It's really weird. If I connect via the mongodb-js driver everything works fine. CRUD works like a charm.

Here's how I connect via MongoClient:

```
let dbURL = 'myAtlasConnectionURL';
let db = await MongoClient.connect(dbURL);
await db.collection('users').insert({name: 'username'});
let result = await db.collection('users').find({});
log.info('result', await result.toArray());
db.collection('users').remove({});
await db.close();
```

But if use the mongoose connection I keep getting:

```
MongoError: connection 5 to cluster0-shard-00-02-c4nst.mongodb.net:27017 closed
at Function.MongoError.create (/mypath/vendors/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:29:11)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/mypath/vendors/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:202:22)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:316:30)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:548:12)
```

Here's how I try to connect via mongoose, using the same dbURL as above:

```
mongoose.connect(dbURL, {
  useMongoClient: true
});
```

I have no idea, what could possibly be wrong.

Comment: This https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5399 might be of interest to you.

Comment: @Veram thanks, for pointing me the discussion. That looks quite bleak to me. At least I know, that should not follow that mongoose road any further.

Comment: I dunno if it is too late to help anyone with this but I was having much the same issue trying to get Mongoose 5.2.7 to connect to Atlas MongoDB cloud. I ended up needing to use the long URL that specifies all of the replica cluster members and then it started working. The url looks like mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00-xxxxx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-xxxxx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-xxxxx.mongodb.net:27017/MyDbHere?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true